# finding y-coordinate of a 4-torsion point on elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

I found the `x`-coordinate of my 4-torsion point on `E`: $y^2=x^3-3267x+45630$ given by $x=15\pm 36B$ with $B^2=-2$. My question here is how am I to find the `y`-coordinate of this 4-torsion point?

Comment: $y= \pm \sqrt{x^3-3267x+45630}$

Comment: @user1952009. i tried doing that with no success.. by trying an error so many times I manage to get $y$-coordinate as $27*a*(a^2-4*B-5)$ where $a^4-5*a^2-32=0$. But how to get it straight away without trying an error.

Comment: Have you done the [reduction modulo $p$](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2013/REUPapers/Galperin.pdf) ?

Comment: What do you mean by finding the $y$-coordinate of the point? Do you expect it to be defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$? What kind of expression are you looking for?

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo Yes I want it to be defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ I actually try an error so many times until I get the answer y-coordinate = $27a(a^2−4B−5)$ where $a^4−5a^2−32=0$ using Sage. I did such a way that I equate LHS expression of my elliptic curve to RHS and play around to make them equal to get y-coordinate. But is there a way I can get it straight away without having to try an error.

Comment: I am confused, because the $y$ coordinate is *not* defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ but over a quartic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. In fact, the poynomial defining $a$ in your comment here is a quartic, and then you are writing $y$ defined over this quartic extension.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo sorry my mistake I have been confused. Since I have the $x$-coordinate in $\mathbb{Q}\sqrt{-2}$, so I assumed that $y$-coordinate should be over $\mathbb{Q}\sqrt{-2}$ as well. y-coordinate is actually defined over the quartic extension. And the thing is that I got the $y$-coordinate by trying an error. Is there a way I can know the y-coordinate. I sub the x-coordinate into my elliptic curve expression and got this $y^2=186624*B - 116640$.

Comment: I think that's the best you can do. The field of definition of the $y$ coordinate is a quartic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ that is *not* Galois. The Galois closure of $\mathbb{Q}(y)$ is of degree 8 over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo.. Your feedback has been so helpful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the [elliptic-curves] tagged questions these days, found this post, which is already answered in the comments. Maybe i should say some words, that would not fit in a comment. Here is what i am doing in such situations. We want to compute
$$
\sqrt{x^3-3267x+45630}\ ,\qquad\text { for the special value }x=15+36B\ ,\ B=\sqrt{-2}\ .
$$
By chance, the number under the square root may be a square in the field $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-2})=\Bbb Q(B)$. Let us see if this is the case.

```
sage: K.<B> = QuadraticField(-2)
sage: def f(x):    return x^3 - 3267*x + 45630

sage: f(15+36*B)
-186624*B - 116640

sage: f(15+36*B).factor()
(-B - 1)^8 * (B - 1)^6 * B^10 * (-2*B + 3)

sage: (3-2*B).norm()
17

sage: (3-2*B).is_square()
False
```

We need to adjoin a root of it.
So the factor $3-2B=3-2\sqrt{-2}$ of norm $17$ is the problem in this case.
(All other factors come at even powers.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback.